# jquery add not-in-dom element in a ordered stack (in-dom elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unexpected problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div2" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div3" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div5" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div6" class="myDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var $divs = $('.myDiv');
    // create new div not in tree
    var $div = $('<div/>').attr("id","div4").addClass('myDiv');
    // insert #div4 in right position. Only in stack, not in dom tree.
    $divs = $divs.slice(0,3).add($div).add($divs.slice(3));

    console.log($divs);
});
```

**output**

> [div#div1.myDiv, div#div2.myDiv, div#div3.myDiv, div#div5.myDiv, div#div6.myDiv, *div#div4.myDiv*]

**Warning: I DON'T want to insert it in dom tree (like `$div.appendBefore($divs[3])`), I just want append it in my stack `$divs`.**

I thought that this stack was an ordered list. So, my goal was to create on fly a `#div4` and insert it in `$divs` stack without insert it in DOM tree. The insert works but it seems that jquery ignore the order given.

I've other solutions for this problem (i.e. append in dom with a display none), ok.. but:

**My question is: why?** It's a bug for some cache optimization, or it's a documented feature?

I've also tried:

```
var $newDivs = $();
$divs.each(function(i,e) {
    if(i==3) 
        $newDivs = $newDivs.add($div);
    $newDivs = $newDivs.add(e);
});
console.log($newDivs);
```

but the output is the same.

EDIT: Just for completeness: this was just a fast hack for a complex code. I know that the purpose is not clean

Comment: Not an answer to your "why?" question, but should do what you want : `$('#div3').after($div)`

Comment: @LeGEC I want to insert #div4 in right position (before div5). Only in stack, not in dom tree.

Comment: @WTK in jquery doc there are words like "stack" and "push", "insert onto"... For this I thought to an ordered list. I never needed to manipulate order of runtime jquery elements (and if I did it I used a simple array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the purpose of a jQuery object. KEep your data-structures straight; I'm not sure how the concept of a 'stack' came into this at all. Use the regular built in JS arrays (which keep items ordered):

```
$(function() {
    // make an array of existing divs
    var divs = $('.myDiv').toArray();

    // create new div
    var newDiv = $('<div/>').attr("id","div4").addClass('myDiv').get(0);

    // insert newDiv at index 4 in array
    divs.splice(4, 0, newDiv);

    // Rejoice.
    console.log(divs);
});
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it I was just about to post same answer with use of toArray and splice :)

Comment: Thank you. However, my purpose was a fast hack (in a more more complex plugin) for don't change the type of original var. So all my `$divs.each` in this case cannot works.

Comment: I see now that `$(divs)` create another stack in the right order.

Comment: @chumkiu It creates another *jQuery object*, yes. None of these is a stack. Anyway, it is also possible to iterate JS arrays, using jQuery or otherwise: `$.each(divs, function);` Mostly as an aside, since it sounds like you've figured out the idea.

Comment: @nbrooks If you see the doc of `.pushStack` or `end` or `andSlef` you can see the word `stack` and `push onto` and `return stack`. But ok... it's another question. As I said, it was just an hack and never I thought that use jquery object like array before now. So thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

One more variant of nbrooks answer

```
// get regular array of matched DOM nodes
var divs = $('.myDiv').toArray(); 
// require you to find out on which position you need to put your new div
divs.splice(2, 0, $('<div/>').attr("id","div4").addClass('myDiv').get(0))
// again wrap in jQuery to get what you need
divs = $(divs);
```

Comment: +1 for `divs = $(divs)` that solve my original problem. :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

*As of jQuery 1.4 the results from .add() will always be returned in document order (rather than a simple concatenation).*

It's documented behaviour, it's not a normal array.

http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 1):

Really seems not a jquery behaviour but more a javascript browser's native code implementation as
i get these results, depending of which browser is used (windows7):

- Firefox and IE9: 1,2,3,5,6,**4**
- Safari : 1,2,3,**4**,5,6
- Chrome: **4**,1,2,3,5,6